# Как убрать кавычки у каждого элемента списка?

Tags: python, json, парсер

У меня есть список:

```
['{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"area": 1}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[0.0002700000000000001, 90.00026999999932],[0.0005400000000000066, 90.00026999999932],[0.0002700000000000001, 90.00053999999865],[0.0005400000000000066, 90.00053999999865]]]}}',
 '{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"area": 2}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[0.0002700000000000001, 90.00053999999865],[0.0005400000000000066, 90.00053999999865],[0.0002700000000000001, 90.00080999999795],[0.0005400000000000066, 90.00080999999795]]]}}',
 '{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"area": 3}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[0.0002700000000000001, 90.00080999999795],[0.0005400000000000066, 90.00080999999795],[0.0002700000000000001, 90.00107999999727],[0.0005400000000000066, 90.00107999999727]]]}}']
```

Весь список мне нужно преобразовать в JSON. Для этого хочу превратить список вот такой формат:

```
[{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"area": 1}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[0.0002700000000000001, 90.00026999999932],[0.0005400000000000066, 90.00026999999932],[0.0002700000000000001, 90.00053999999865],[0.0005400000000000066, 90.00053999999865]]]}},
 {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"area": 2}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[0.0002700000000000001, 90.00053999999865],[0.0005400000000000066, 90.00053999999865],[0.0002700000000000001, 90.00080999999795],[0.0005400000000000066, 90.00080999999795]]]}},
 {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"area": 3}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[0.0002700000000000001, 90.00080999999795],[0.0005400000000000066, 90.00080999999795],[0.0002700000000000001, 90.00107999999727],[0.0005400000000000066, 90.00107999999727]]]}}]
```

Т. е. убрать кавычки у каждого элемента списка.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Ответил на Ваш предыдущий вопрос, чтобы не было таких костылей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

воспользуйтесь [json.loads()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) чтобы распарсить каждую строку списка в JSON объект (`dictionary`):

```
import json

res = [json.loads(s) for s in lst]
```

результат:

```
In [33]: res
Out[33]:
[{'type': 'Feature',
  'properties': {'area': 1},
  'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
   'coordinates': [[[0.0002700000000000001, 90.00026999999932],
     [0.0005400000000000066, 90.00026999999932],
     [0.0002700000000000001, 90.00053999999865],
     [0.0005400000000000066, 90.00053999999865]]]}},
 {'type': 'Feature',
  'properties': {'area': 2},
  'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
   'coordinates': [[[0.0002700000000000001, 90.00053999999865],
     [0.0005400000000000066, 90.00053999999865],
     [0.0002700000000000001, 90.00080999999795],
     [0.0005400000000000066, 90.00080999999795]]]}},
 {'type': 'Feature',
  'properties': {'area': 3},
  'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
   'coordinates': [[[0.0002700000000000001, 90.00080999999795],
     [0.0005400000000000066, 90.00080999999795],
     [0.0002700000000000001, 90.00107999999727],
     [0.0005400000000000066, 90.00107999999727]]]}}]
```